# ServiceStack Typescript client not loading dictionary

Tags: typescript, servicestack

I have an endpoint from my ServiceStack API that returns a dictionary as part of the returned object.  The rest of the object is being populated as expected, but the dictionary portion is just being returned as an empty object.  This is my first attempt at using the ServiceStack typescript client and im at a loss as to why this is happening.  Hitting the endpoint with axios works as expected, but we really would like to be able to use the ServiceStack client instead of axios.

The call using the ServiceStack client:

```
getTotals = async (financialPeriodType: any, entityId: any) => {
    const client = new JsonServiceClient('apiAddress');
    client.bearerToken = this.context.JWTToken;
    client.credentials = 'omit';

    const request = new ServiceStack.GetFinancialTotals();
    request.financialPeriodType = financialPeriodType;
    request.entityId = entityId;

    const ret = await client.get(request);
    console.log(ret.result);
    return ret.result;
};
```

the DTO that should have a dictionary populated:

```
export class GetFinancialTotalsModel {
    public entityId: string;
    public financialPeriodType: FinancialPeriodType;
    public totalCost: number;
    public budgetAmount: number;
    public savingsAmount: number;
    public productCategoryCosts: { [index: string]: number };

    public constructor(init?: Partial<GetFinancialTotalsModel>) {
        (Object as any).assign(this, init);
    }
}
```

Everything is getting populated correctly other than the productCategoryCosts which is being populated as an empty object

Comment: Could you please share your TypeScript code?

Comment: added the client call and the dto in question that was generated by ServiceStack

Comment: Please also include the HTTP Response that's being returned and the original C# DTO.

Answer (score 0):

There's no "deserialization step" with TypeScript, i.e. the TypeScript classes only provides the static Type info for what's returned, if something's not populated then it's not being returned, have a look at the raw JSON response to see what is being returned.